# AWS architecture for an application which streams video stored in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have an application where videos are stored in S3 and those videos are streamed in mobile apps just like youtube videos. Each file might be of 1+ GB. Is just S3 enough for storing and streaming the video? Which aws service should I use and what would be its architecture?

Comment: Kinesis Video streams perhaps?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/choose-the-right-aws-video-service-for-your-use-case/

Comment: @DevangSanghani need the videos stored in S3 to be streamed to mobile apps. It this what's needed?

Comment: Is your 'streaming' question related to _sending_ the videos to S3, or _playing_ the videos from S3? How are the videos sent to S3 -- is it after the have finished filming, or _while_ they are filming?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Videos are uploaded to S3 by backend cms. Then the streaming URL is sent to mobile for streaming. The same video could be streamed in multiple resolutions just like in youtube.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to stream videos from Amazon S3 would be to use **Amazon CloudFront**, which can handle the streaming protocols. However, your videos will **possibly need to be converted to a suitable format**.

See:

- [Tutorial: Hosting on-demand streaming video with Amazon S3, Amazon CloudFront, and Amazon Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tutorial-s3-cloudfront-route53-video-streaming.html)
- [Delivering video on demand (VOD) with CloudFront - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/on-demand-video.html)

Alternatively, you can use the **AWS Elemental** services that are designed specifically for handling video and streaming. AWS Elemental MediaConvert can convert video files into suitable formats.

See:

- [Media Streaming Tutorials | CDN, Video Hosting, Distribution | Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/)
- [Streaming Optimized Videos From AWS S3 in Minutes | CSS-Tricks - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/streaming-optimized-videos-from-aws-s3-in-minutes/)